# display video camera on two different windows tkinter python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i have a GUI python application that contain two different function windows and i'am trying to display video camera in the second window of tkinter application.
But, the video frame always be showing on the first windows!! i don't know if it is a problem of threads, or camera librairy. is there any fault in my code?
thanks in advance.

```
# add the necessairy librairy
    import tkinter as tk
    import threading
    import time
    import subprocess
    from imutils.video import VideoStream
    import time
    import imutils
    import cv2
    import argparse
    from PIL import Image
    from PIL import ImageTk
    
    class PhotoBoothApp:
        def __init__(self,vs):
            # store the video stream object and output path, then initialize
            # the most recently read frame, thread for reading frames, and
            # the thread stop event
    
            self.vs = vs
            self.frame = None
            self.thread = None
            self.stopEvent_2 = None
    
            # initialize the root window and image panel
            self.root = tk.Tk()
            self.panel = None
            self.user_input = tk.StringVar(self.root)
            self.but_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
            w = 800 # width for the Tk root
            h = 500 # height for the Tk root
            # get screen width and height
            ws = self.root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
            hs = self.root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen
            # calculate x and y coordinates for the Tk master window
            x = (ws/3) - (w/3)
            y = (hs/3) - (h/3)
            # set the dimensions of the screen 
            # and where it is placed
            self.root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
            # when open the second window i want it to be on toplevel; it means when i click outside the frame it won't get hide
            self.root.title("Test thread")
    
            # create a button, that when pressed, will take the current
            # frame and save it to file
            btn = tk.Button(self.but_frame, bd = '5',text=" photo ")
            
            self.but_frame.pack(side="left")
                    
            # start a thread that constantly pools the video sensor for
            # the most recently read frame
            self.stopEvent_2 = threading.Event()
            self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.videoLoop, args=())
            self.thread.start()
    
            # set a callback to handle when the window is closed
            self.root.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.onClose)

        def videoLoop(self):
            # DISCLAIMER:
            # I'm not a GUI developer, nor do I even pretend to be. This
            # try/except statement is a pretty ugly hack to get around
            # a RunTime error that Tkinter throws due to threading
    
            try:
                # keep looping over frames until we are instructed to stop
                while not self.stopEvent_2.is_set():
                    # grab the frame from the video stream and resize it to
                    # have a maximum width of 300 pixels
                    self.frame = self.vs.read()
                    self.frame = imutils.resize(self.frame, width=300)
    
                    #cv2.imshow('video player', self.frame) 
            
                    # OpenCV represents images in BGR order; however PIL
                    # represents images in RGB order, so we need to swap
                    # the channels, then convert to PIL and ImageTk format
                    image = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                    image = Image.fromarray(image)
                    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            
                    # if the panel is not None, we need to initialize it
                    if self.panel is None:
                        self.panel = tk.Label(image=image)
                        self.panel.image = image
                        self.panel.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)
            
                    # otherwise, simply update the panel
                    else:
                        self.panel.configure(image=image)
                        self.panel.image = image
    
            except RuntimeError :
                print("[INFO] caught a RuntimeError_________________________________________")
    
        def onClose(self):
            # set the stop event, cleanup the camera, and allow the rest of
            # the quit process to continue
            print("[INFO] closing...")
            self.stopEvent_2.set()
            self.vs.stop()
            self.root.quit()
    
       
    # here's the main window
    Mafenetre = tk.Tk()
    #set main window title
    Mafenetre.title("GUI")
    Mafenetre['bg']='white' # couleur de fond
    # get screen width and height
    wf1= Mafenetre.winfo_screenwidth()
    hf1= Mafenetre.winfo_screenheight()
    A = str(wf1)
    B = str(hf1)
    # set the dimensions of the screen 
    # and where it is placed
    
    w = 500 # width for the Tk root
    h = 500 # height for the Tk root
    # get screen width and height
    ws = Mafenetre.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
    hs = Mafenetre.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen
    # calculate x and y coordinates for the Tk master window
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    # set the dimensions of the screen 
    # and where it is placed
    Mafenetre.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
    # add test button to the main window
    reglage = tk.Button(Mafenetre, bd = '5',text="  PARAM  ", bg='#c42034', fg='white',font= "Helvetica", 12))
    reglage.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=6,pady=35)
    camera = VideoStream(0).start()
    pba = PhotoBoothApp(camera)
    Mafenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because you created the label `self.panel` without passing the parent to `Label(...)` so the label will be created in the first instance of `Tk()` which is `Mafenetre`.

Comment: i have tried this 'self.panel = tk.Label(self.root, image=image)' and 'self.panel = tk.Label(self.frame, image=image)' but it doesn't work.!! any help

Comment: What does *"It doesn't work"* mean? Is the video still shown in main window or no video shown at all?

Comment: no video shown at all here's the error
  `File "test_2cams.py", line 88, in videoLoop
    self.panel = tk.Label(self.root, image=image)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop`